# Using nested lists as input to non-vectorized a function

Tags: r, list, lapply

I need to use nested elements in a list for a query. For example:

```
sha_list <- list(c("ed76504696469470dcbf", "164f798524fd6904236a"),
c("669dfeccad88cd4348f7", "af70a76691aacf05c1bb"))
```

This is a list which has the following structure:

```
[[1]]
[1] "ed76504696469470dcbf" "164f798524fd6904236a"

[[2]]
[1] "669dfeccad88cd4348f7" "af70a76691aacf05c1bb"
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
library("devtools")
lapply(sha_list, source_gist)
```

this gives:

```
Error: length(id) == 1 is not TRUE
```

The expected output would be a list with two elements in each of the two entries of the list:

```
[[1]]
[1] gist1
[2] gist2

[[2]]
[1] gist3
[2] gist4
```

What I need to do here is to iterate across this list to execute a function (which is non-vectorized, so it can only take one of the elements as an argument at a time). I was hoping that this would work, since I want to recursively use each item in each list:

```
rapply(sha_list, source_gist, how = "list")
```

This doesn't work either.

`unlist()` will not work, because I need to maintain the structure of the list (i.e. the output needs to be structured in the same way, as a list).

Comment: Try `lapply(unlist(sha_list), source_gist)`

Comment: Or `lapply(sha_list, function(x) lapply(x, source_gist))` to maintain the structure of the list

Comment: @choff - The structure of the list will remain unchanged in my call, so long as you do not re-assign `unlist(sha_list)` to `sha_list`

Comment: @RichardScriven But it will change the length of the list to 4, no?

Comment: @histelheim, what output are you expecting? You are sourcing gists here, which may become complicated in the manor you are describing.  I would suggest one gist in each element of a four element list

Comment: @RichardScriven: I've added the expected output.

Comment: @choff: correct, this changes the length of the list to 4, whereas it should be 2, with 2 nested elements inside of each sublist.

Comment: @choff: if you want to put your solution in an answer I can accept it..it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
library("devtools")
sha_list <- list(c("ed76504696469470dcbf", "164f798524fd6904236a"),
                 c("669dfeccad88cd4348f7", "af70a76691aacf05c1bb"))
my.gists <- lapply(sha_list, function(x) lapply(x, source_gist))
```

Then, for example, the gist associated with `sha_list[[1]][2]` can be accessed with `my.gists[[1]][[2]]`.